# How to log MDC with Spring Sleuth?

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a Spring boot + sleuth based application. All works as expected. I have for now logs like this:

```
2017-05-04 17:55:52.226  INFO [alert,692d0eeca479e216,c3c8b680dc29ad02,false] 17292 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] c.k.a.b.s.alert.impl.AlertServiceImpl    : Alert state to process: xxx
```

Now, I want to add custom MDC to my log like the contract reference for example. I want to have logs like this:

```
2017-05-04 17:55:52.226  INFO [alert,692d0eeca479e216,c3c8b680dc29ad02,false] [CONTRACT_REF] 17292 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] c.k.a.b.s.alert.impl.AlertServiceImpl    : Alert state to process: xxx
```

I tried various things with no success:

1. Use the Spring Sleuth Tracer to add a tag;
2. Add logging.pattern.level=%5p %mdc to my application.properties file with MDC.put(xxx, xxx)

How can I add custom MDC/tags to my log?

Comment: Would you please share some minimum code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For versions before 2.x, You have to create your own implementation of a `SpanLogger`. The easiest way will be to extend the `Slf4jSpanLogger` and provide your own code to add / update and remove the entries from MDC context. Then you can change your logging pattern and that way your logs will contain what they need.

Comment: Should I put a tag in a span and then use this tag record when setting MDC in Slf4jSpanLogger?

Comment: hi @Marcin Grzejszczak 
im using spring boot 2.2.5, how i can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add data to the MDC fairly easily by doing `MDC.put("yourCoolKey", "your cool value")` (see [MDC.put JavaDoc](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))).

Once you `put` the value into the `MDC`, you can use the sequence `%X{yourCoolKey}` in your logging pattern (in my case, the value of `logging.pattern.console`) to print the string `"your cool value"` as part of each log statement.

Optionally, you can specify a default value in the pattern string by adding `:-<defaultValue>` after the key, such as `%X{yourCoolKey:-N/A}`, which will print the string `"N/A"` whenever the MDC does not have an entry for `"yourCoolKey"`. The default, if not specified, is a blank string (`""`)