# How to log MDC with Spring Sleuth 2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

referring to quesition/answer in [How to log MDC with Spring Sleuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43787815/how-to-log-mdc-with-spring-sleuth/49581661#49581661)
I think this has/will change(d) with spring-cloud 2.0 as there is no `SpanLogger` or `Slf4jSpanLogger` anymore (or I don't find it)

Wouldn't it be nice if application properties `spring.sleuth.baggage-keys` and `spring.sleuth.propagation-keys` if set would also be put in MDC I think inside `Slf4jCurrentTraceContext` (as this class is currently `final` I cannot subclass it)

If not, how could I achieve this with spring-cloud 2.0 accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't want to put all entries in MDC (that really doesn't make a lot of sense). You can however either copy the `Slf4jCurrentTraceContext` and extend it in the way you want to (and register it as a bean) or maybe create your own implementation of `CurrentTraceContext` that would wrap the existing `CurrentTraceContext` via a Bean Post Processor and perform additional logic. I guess the first option is more preferable.

Answer (score 3):

In version `2.1.0`, `Slf4jScopeDecorator` was introduced and it will automatically add baggage values to MDC as long as they are whitelisted in the `spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.whitelisted-mdc-keys` configuration.

For example, if you have the following configuration:

```
spring.sleuth.baggage-keys=key1,key2
spring.sleuth.log.slf4j.whitelisted-mdc-keys=key2
```

Only the value of `key2` will be automatically added MDC, but not the value of `key1`.

For more info, see: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#prefixed-fields