# log MDC with Spring Cloud Sleuth 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I would like to include the `spring.sleuth.propagation-keys` into the MDC.
Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581760/how-to-log-mdc-with-spring-sleuth-2-0) we can create our own implementation of `CurrentTraceContext` similar to `Slf4jCurrentTraceContext`.

However cannot get the value via since the `ExtraFieldPropagation.Extra` class is package private:

`((ExtraFieldPropagation.Extra) currentSpan.extra().get(0)).values[0];`

if I set:

`spring:
  sleuth:
    propagation-keys: trId`

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. Works with: `ExtraFieldPropagation.get(currentSpan, "trId")`